# Minimize/close button design in “Join” box is broken

Tags: bug, design

For communities where you still don’t have an account you do see the Join box at the top of the page. This box currently contains a broken minimize/close button:

> [image: join]

You can see the same for any site opened in browser private mode.

Comment: Looks like it's broken for the old-style banner regardless of whether you're looking at the Join page, or a fully anonymous view. The button itself *works*, it's just styled wrong.

Comment: @AdamLear hence tagged [design] not [implementation] ;)

Comment: I'm just leaving a note because "broken" when it comes to buttons usually implies "it doesn't do anything" :)

Comment: @AdamLear my English still isn’t perfect ;)