# Are there any questions closed by 5 moderators?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderators

Inspired by [this question on Worldbuilding Meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6730/8732), where a user noted that a question was closed by two ♦ moderators:

[image]

For some people it might be obvious what happened here: one of the moderators wasn't a moderator when closing the question, so their vote only counted as one.

A collector of Stack Exchange curiosa will naturally ask the following question: is there *any* question in the network closed by five people who are now moderators (as part of regular close voting, not [testing the API](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289395/295232))?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is (at the moment of posting) **no**; there are quite a few questions closed by 4 now-moderators, but none by 5. [This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/906091/questions-closed-by-multiple-moderators-networkwide) lists all of them, here are a couple of results across the network:

- [Need a decent wallpaper changer for Ubuntu 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/q/65929/606366) (Ask Ubuntu)
- [how to correct merge rasters with different projections?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/82898/85703) (GIS)
- [Como lidar com múltiplas áreas de logins no Laravel?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1977/57567) (pt.SO)
- [When will the sitecore azure search provider be released?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/312/1542) (Sitecore)
- [Is there a more elegent solution for exponentially weighted-mean in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/50466/79696) (Cross Validated)
- https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/53420/28333 (Travel)

Most questions are from [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

<sub>The list with ♦ moderators was scraped from [here](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators) and is not updated automatically. For that reason, and the fact that some closed questions are deleted by e.g. [Roomba](/help/roomba), the list above may be outdated. Feel free to fork the SEDE query to make an updated list.</sub>

Comment: Did you try to add Community user in moderator list? I know that technically this user isn't a moderator. But it has a diamond :)

Comment: No, and employees aren't included either. I haven't checked all questions closed by 4 moderators in the query results, but I doubt there will be cases where Community is the 5th user.

Comment: Community on the 5th place is [ordinary case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314753/339911).

Comment: Did the third one get reopened after you posted or something?  I'm not seeing that one as closed.  Or is it something to do with how SEDE might treat reopened questions?

Comment: @JMac the Ask Ubuntu one? https://i.stack.imgur.com/73gy4.png

Comment: @Glorfindel Oh that's weird.  I wasn't registered for that site, and for some reason that link was taking me right to the [marked duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu) without saying anything.  I registered for ask Ubuntu and refreshed, still  the same page.  Then I closed the tab and clicked the link again, and it took me to the right one.  Does it automatically take people who aren't logged in to linked duplicates instead of closed questions?

Comment: Yes, that's a [known feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125220/295232). I could have avoided that by adding `?noredirect=1` to the URLs but I'm lazy ... and it messes up Meta's feature to automatically determine question titles from bare URLs.

Comment: Interesting... did you count also posts on all site's Metas as well?

Comment: @DarkCygnus I thought I had, and they are selected, but there's a mistake in showing the results since the `#sites` table doesn't contain metas. I found [one question on a child meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1325/) closed by 4 moderators, none by 5. The query has been updated, thanks for asking about it!

Comment:  = [Known](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oxymoron) + [feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undocumented_feature).

Comment: Hi @Glorfindel could there have been an update to this list after the appointment of the MSE-mods?

Comment: And there are questions closed only by mods (and more than 1 o/c). (not exactly what was asked, but ...   MSE example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146460/why-is-downvoting-a-question-free-but-downvoting-an-answer-not)

Comment: [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/906091/questions-closed-by-multiple-moderators-networkwide) is an update, but no new records. There are no questions here on Meta closed by 3 or more moderators. I suspect there are plenty closed by two.

Comment: Only two of your questions are still (a) visible and (b) closed by 4 now-mods.